# Is there any way to hide a Puppeteer browser that has the option 'headless: false'?

Tags: javascript, browser, electron, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am working on an electron application that makes use of Puppeteer for some process.

This is the block of code I use to summon browsers:

```
var browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    defaultViewport: { width: 1920, height:1080 },
});
```

For specific reasons, I need the headless option to be false for the app to work, but at the same time I would like it if the app didn't actually bring up visible web browsers.

Is there any way (and I really mean ANY way. docker containers, remote servers, etc. I'm open to any and all suggestions) I can make these browsers invisible to the user while keeping the `headless: false` line of code?

I couldn't find any similar questions for this.

Thank You

Comment: Different machine, docker container (http://www.smartjava.org/content/using-puppeteer-in-docker-copy-2/) or perhaps `--window-workspace` option (https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/; but I didn't make it work during my quick experiment now).

Comment: @pavelsaman thank you so much for your response and the resources!!! I will look into this, leave the experimenting to me!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use use [`xvfb`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb).

Add the code below into your `puppeteer.launch` arguments.

```
{
  headless: false,
  args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-gpu']
}
```

To run, use the command `xvfb-run node code.js`

You can read more about this [here](https://www.mattzeunert.com/2018/07/21/running-headful-chrome-on-ubuntu-server.html).